# How do you pass authentication from an RTK Query to firebase functions to access realtime database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, rtk-query

In the frontend, everything is authenticated properly using the firebase signin api, and a listener for auth changes to get the token and User info to pass to the backend.

this is the general fields used in RTK Query:

```
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://us-central1.cloudfunctions.net/api",
    mode: "cors",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
      const authToken = localStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
      if (authToken) headers.set("authorization", authToken);
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getWorkouts: builder.query<GetWorkoutList, string>({
      query: (userId) => ({
        url: `/workouts/${userId}`,
      }),
    }),
---rest of endpoints---
```

and this it is checking for successful frontend authentication changes:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (userInfo) => {
      setUser(userInfo);
      if (userInfo === null) {
        localStorage.clear();
      } else {
        const token = await userInfo.getIdToken(true);
        localStorage.setItem("AuthToken", `Bearer ${token}`);
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [user]);
```

In firebase functions, it is using admin levels to verify the token from the frontend and the rest of the backend is using regular user permissions.

```
const decodedIdToken = await adminApp.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
```

The problem is that using the admin level bypasses the security rules and doesn't actually provide the authentication for a user to reach the database.

What is the actual step that is missing to give the request to the realtime database the authentication object for firebase rules to be successfully passed.

```
    "users":{
      "$userId":{
        ".write": "$userId == auth.uid",
        ".read": "$userId == auth.uid",
      },
    },
```

(auth == null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests from the Admin SDK are normally fully trusted and bypass the security rules.

For the Realtime Database though you can pass a `databaseAuthVariableOverride` when initializing the Admin SDK, and pass your own UID as shown in the documentation on [authenticating with limited privileges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges). Although I've never tested this myself, I think you might be able to pass other claims too - as the information you pass just becomes the `auth` variable in the rules.

Comment: Is there no way to do it through the regular channels? How is req.auth usually created without forcing it with admin privileges?

Comment: The `auth` variable in security rules is automatically populated by the relevant backend service from the auth information. The only way to pass that information from an Admin SDK is through the variable I indicated in my answer. I'm not sure what problem you see with that though. Did you try it yet? Can you clarify what didn't work about it?

Comment: I don't necessarily see it as a problem. I just want to understand the options. My question was more directed about asking how the auth variable can be populated without relying on the admin SDK. In my frontend, I am able to sign in and get the auth data using regular user permissions. So, I have been confused why I can't seem to find a way to do the same thing in the backend as well. I've assumed there is a way to populate the auth payload in my request without resorting to elevating my permissions because my client side has already authenticated and signed in the user.

Comment: There's no concept of a currently signed in user in the Admin SDKs. If you need a signed in user, consider using the regular (non-Admin) JavaScript SDK, which also works on back-end systems.

Comment: I have been trying to, but nothing has worked to get through the firebase rules. I have tried signing in in the backend and setting a listener for any auth changes. But none of that has populated the auth variable.

Comment: For clarification about my fire base functions, my requests to the realtime database are not using admin privileges. The only time I have been using admin privileges was while verifying the token from the client request

Comment: I checked with a team mate, and the two options we can think of would be to mint a custom token with the same data from the ID token and then signing into the regular JavaScript SDK with that, or to call the REST API with the ID token you get. Neither is easy though, but both should work.